# How to standardize an RDD in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have created testing and training data as follows:

```
data = sc.textFile(fileName)
training, testing = data.randomSplit([0.6, 0.4], seed=11L)
```

Now I want to standardize each feature. I found StandardScaler and I want to use the following code to do that:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaledFeatures", withStd=True, withMean=True)  

# Compute summary statistics by fitting the StandardScaler
scalerModel = scaler.fit(training)

# Normalize each Train feature to have unit standard deviation.
scaledTrainData = scalerModel.transform(training)

# Normalize each Test feature to have unit standard deviation.
scaledTestData = scalerModel.transform(testing)
```

but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-32380b939084> in <module>()
      6 
      7 # Compute summary statistics by fitting the StandardScaler
----> 8 scalerModel = scaler.fit(training)
      9 
     10 # Normalize each Train feature to have unit standard deviation.

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     67                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     68             else:
---> 69                 return self._fit(dataset)
     70         else:
     71             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    131 
    132     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 133         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    134         return self._create_model(java_model)
    135 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    128         """
    129         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 130         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    131 
    132     def _fit(self, dataset):

AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @LostInOverflow you got me! :D I'm new to Spark, would you plz explain the problem to me.

Comment: Short: `StandardScaler` operates on `DataFrames`. `DataFrames` have columns (input and output ones are defined when you create scaler). `sc.textFile` creates `RDD`. It is just a collection of lines. There are no features to scale, and certainly no columns. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html has a lot of nice examples. Please start with these :) (converting to data frame, casting, feature extraction, assembling and so on).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you imported the StandardScaler library from pyspark.ml.feature, which expects a dataframe. Try to run "from pyspark.mllib.feature import StandardScaler, StandardScalerModel" before your code.